# Math.round cant do negative numbers c#

Tags: c#

I have a homework where im supposed to create a code which should let the user type in a decimal number and then ask how many decimals the user want the number to be rounded to. The homework assignment were given to us with minimal instruction on how to do it so we were supposed to look online. We were given a hint about Math.Round() and this is my code right now:

```
        Console.WriteLine("Hej! Skriv in ett tal med decimaler.");           
        string strTal = Console.ReadLine();    
        double tal = Convert.ToDouble(strTal); 
        Console.WriteLine("Tack! Skriv nu in hur många decimaler du 
        vill ha med på ditt tal.");
        string strAvrundaren = Console.ReadLine();
        int avrundaren = Convert.ToInt32(strAvrundaren); 


        Console.WriteLine("Ditt tal är: " + 
        Math.Round(tal,avrundaren));
```

With this code I got it to work so that whenever the user writes a decimal number and then writes the x amount of decimals it should be rounded to it does so correctly. My problem is that I had the thought if someone were to input a negative decimal number (ex:  -1, -2, -2,12313 etc..)? I tried and my code crashed when I did it. Now im coming to you guys for an explanation to why it does this.

EDIT: by saying it "crashes", whenever I write in a negative number in the terminal the window pops down to my sidebar and when I bring it back up nothing has happened on the terminal and I can write as much as I want in the terminal but nothing happens. Im on Visual Studio for the Mac if that helps.

Best Regards 
Kian

Comment: Why not apply the negative after you round a positive number? num * -1

Comment: Did you read the error message?

Comment: "my code crashed" can you be more precise? I'm guessing that `avrundaren` is negative and you get an error on `Math.Round` but we'd need to know for sure before suggesting an answer.

Comment: Use the debugger to see the exception message.

Comment: @DStanley That information is already provided in the question.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek: It wasn't when DStanley wrote the comment. My guess is that's an exception - I'd suggest the OP spends some more time learning how to diagnose issues in their environment (e.g. stepping through in the debugger, and finding out more about exception handling in their environment) so they can see the exception.

Comment: `Math.Round` [works for negatives](https://dotnetfiddle.net/TEFofv)

Comment: @CodingYoshi - I think the question is about entering a negative number for the _second_ parameter to `Math.Round`, which does cause that method to throw an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`.

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes it was: *"My problem is that I had the thought if someone were to input a negative decimal number (ex: -1, -2, -2,12313 etc..)? I tried and my code crashed when I did it."*. I'd advise you both to at least read the question fully first. The title also clearly stated this.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek: DStanley asked for more precision than "my code crashed" - what you quoted didn't provide that precision. Did the process just terminate? Was an exception thrown? If so, where and what was the exception? These things are important - "my code crashed" is not useful; a full exception with a stack trace is.

Comment: @JonSkeet It is useful yes, but that's wasn't my argument. It's useful information to provide, but there is enough here to mark this as a duplicate/give an answer.

Comment: This is what I wrote in response to being more precise for how the code crashes:

"by saying it "crashes", whenever I write in a negative number in the terminal the window pops down to my sidebar and when I bring it back up nothing has happened on the terminal and I can write as much as I want in the terminal but nothing happens. Im on Visual Studio for the Mac if that helps."

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek: My reading of DStanley's comment was asking for more precision on the nature of the crash, which seems *entirely* reasonable to me. And no, the OP didn't state that "avrundaren is negative" - they stated that "the decimal number" (`tal`, not `avrundaren`) is negative. DStanley is speculating - again, reasonably IMO - that it's actually the second number that's negative, not the first. Of course, if the OP had posted a [mcve] with hard-coded values, that would have been clear.

Comment: @KianParsa: So how are you running the code? What happens if you run it in the debugger? What type of app is it? (You talk about "the window" - which window? The terminal window? It's very unclear.) It's almost certain that there's an exception being thrown, but you really, really need to improve your diagnostics so that you can see it. Otherwise, we can help you past this problem but you'll be no better-equipped to fix the *next* exception you run into.

Comment: I got Visual Studio 2017 community for the Macbook Air. When i Run my code there is no errors and it runs smoothly. I dont really know how to explain it better but when I run the code the terminal window pops up. When I write a negative number the terminal window gets minimized to my sidebar and when I try to open it again there is no error or anything and whatever I write nothing happens with the code. When I then try to close the terminal window another windows pops up telling me that if I close the window the active processes: vsdbg, dotnet will be closed/terminated.

Answer (score 1):

Your program lacks input validation. Not only will a negative number cause it to crash, but any string that is not numeric will also cause an unhandled exception.

Typically a program should validate its inputs before attempting to use them. If the value isn't valid, you can ask the user to input it again. Example:

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        double tal;
        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hej! Skriv in ett tal med decimaler.");           
            string strTal = Console.ReadLine();    
            var ok = double.TryParse(strTal, out tal);
            if (ok) break;
        }

        int avrundaren; 
        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Tack! Skriv nu in hur många decimaler du vill ha med på ditt tal.");
            string strAvrundaren = Console.ReadLine();
            var ok = int.TryParse(strAvrundaren, out avrundaren);
            if (!ok) continue;
            if (avrundaren < 0) continue;
            break;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Ditt tal är: " + Math.Round(tal,avrundaren)); 
    }
}
```

Try it on [DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Hbj6s8)

Answer (score 1):

Rounding for negative numbers work: Here is a quick test:

```
var ans = Math.Round(-100.11119, 2);
Console.WriteLine(ans);
```

Please see [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/TEFofv) as proof for above test.

---

If you pass a negative number for the 2nd argument like this:

```
var ans = Math.Round(-100.11119, -2);
Console.WriteLine(ans);
```

You will get a runtime error.

> Run-time exception (line 7): Rounding digits must be between 0 and 15, inclusive.

Please see [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/tZKxIq) for above test.

Therefore, you need to check the number provided to you by the user and make sure it is between 0 and 15 (inclusive).

Comment: Or arbitrarily get the absolute value of whatever number is entered for the 2nd argument, since a negative number here makes no sense.

Comment: @Alan It's probably a much better idea to let the user know it cannot be negative than having the user find out through trial and error you took the absolute value. It causes more confusion that way.

Comment: You are absolutely correct, my suggestion was just an optional fix :)